# Как вывести запись по совпадению?

Tags: php, mysql

База создана в phpmyadmin(тестирую на сервере). Версия php 5.2(использую mysql)
Есть таблица Clients. В таблице, помимо полей Фио, адрес и т.п, есть поля Login и password. 
Имеется кнопка вход. Данные считываются с таблицы Clients, с этих двух полей:

```
<?php

include ("BD_for_users.php");

if(isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password'])) 

{
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
if(empty($login) OR empty($password)){
exit ('<script>alert("Дла начала заполните поля!");</script>');
}

$login = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($login))); 
$password = trim(stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($password))); // надо хранить 
хеш пароля, а не в чистом виде
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE login='".$login."' AND 
password='".$password."'");
$myrow = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($myrow == 1)
{
$_SESSION['login'] = $myrow['login'];
$_SESSION['id'] = $myrow['id'];
echo "Вы успешно вошли на сайт! <a href='For_users.php'>Личный кабинет</a>";
}else{
exit ('<script>alert("Извините, введённый вами логин или пароль неверный.");
</script>');
}
}
?>
```

Как только логин и пароль совпали , клиента перебрасывает в "личный кабинет". На данный момент у меня там просто вывод таблицы:

```
<?php 

 // Подключение к базе: где $hostname - сервер, $username - имя юзера БД, 
// $password - пароль юзера, $basename - имя базы с которой мы будем 
работать 

$hostname = 'localhost'; 
$username = 'root'; 
$passwordname = ''; 
$basename = 'Bank'; 
$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $passwordname, $basename) or die 
('Невозможно открыть базу'); 
// Формируем запрос из таблицы с именем Account 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Account`"; 


$result = $conn->query($sql); 


// В цикле перебираем все записи таблицы и выводим их 
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 

{ 

// Оператором echo выводим на экран поля таблицы name_blog и text_blog 
echo '<tr>'; 
echo '<td>'.$row['id_contribution']; 
echo '</td>'; 
echo '<td>'.$row['account_opening_date']; 
echo '</td>'; 
echo '<td>'.$row['account_closing_date']; 
echo '</td>'; 
echo '<td>'.$row['amount_of_contribution']; 
echo '</td>'; 
echo '</tr>'; 

} 
?>
```

Подскажите, как мне вывести запись клиента по совпадению логина и пароля(или же id). Чтобы каждому клиенту выводилась своя запись

Comment: phpmyadmin тут не причем

Comment: Берете id пользователя из сессии, выбираете строку из БД и выводите

Comment: @Mike $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Account` WHERE `id_client ` = ". (int) $_SESSION['id'];    ?

Comment: ну да, типа того

Comment: @Mike Таблицу пустую выводит :(

Comment: А session_start то где?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Имеется в самом начале, перед html кодом. Я его не скидывал просто

Comment: @Giperion там имеется SQL запрос к БД, которой управляется СУБД например mysql. Phpmyadmin - веб-приложение, представляющее собой веб-интерфейс для администрирования СУБД . И никоим образом php с ним не связан (только тем, что это приложение написано на php). Советую подучить что есть что.